# Site like cplusplus.com for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, sites

One simple question: does anybody know a site like [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) (that has functions and headers nicely organized, includes examples(that is very important to me)) and that it is up to date(C++11).

I ask because I'm unable to find any site like that. Also I can't understand the c++ standard PDF, when it comes to reading out the member functions and stuff like that.

Also googling for specific stuff is often useless (If you don't believe me try to find some atomic header examples).

Comment: I'm reasonably certain no such thing exists **yet**.

Comment: Not many people are comfortable reading the Standard itself.  It wasn't really meant to be read by most programmers.

Comment: I'd say wikipedia is probably the best you'll get for now: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x

Comment: Thank you for the answers   @Necrolis-tnx, but like I said there are no atomic examples, but yeah it's the best thing available AFAIK

Comment: Considering that the final draft was published **yesterday**, I believe Jerry Coffin is on the right track. Patience!

Comment: I know, but GCC and VS already implemented a lot of stuff.  I'm not complaining because that stuff is free and I have no right to "demand" anything. :) I was just wondering. Still wikipedia article is ok, but it doesn't cover everything and it's pretty basic.

Comment: Wikipedia has the same problem - the final document is dated 2011-04-11. **Nobody** except the editor and his review committee has seen the result until **this week**. Now we only have to read the 1350 pages to figure out what C++11 really looks like. Guess Wikipedia will be corrected during this weekend! Or maybe next week? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I surveyed the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx) documentation Ashot refers to.  I thought it would be interesting to note which headers are not standard in this list (are extensions), and which C++11 headers are currently missing.  Here's the results:

```
<algorithm>
<allocators>  // not standard
<array>
<atomic>      // missing
<bitset>
<cassert>
<ccomplex>    // missing
<cctype>
<cerrno>
<cfenv>       // missing
<cfloat>
<chrono>      // missing
<ciso646>
<climits>
<clocale>
<cmath>
<codecvt>
<complex>
<condition_variable>  // missing
<csetjmp>
<csignal>
<cstdarg>
<cstdbool>     // missing
<cstddef>
<cstdint>      // missing
<cstdio>
<cstdlib>
<cstring>
<ctgmath>       // missing
<ctime>
<cvt/wbuffer>  // not standard
<cvt/wstring>  // not standard
<cwchar>
<cwctype>
<deque>
<exception>
<forward_list>
<fstream>
<functional>
<future>      // missing
<hash_map>    // not standard
<hash_set>    // not standard
<initializer_list>  // missing
<iomanip>
<ios>
<iosfwd>
<iostream>
<iso646.h>
<istream>
<iterator>
<limits>
<list>
<locale>
<map>
<memory>
<mutex>        // missing
<new>
<numeric>
<ostream>
<queue>
<random>
<ratio>        // missing
<regex>
<scoped_allocator>  // missing
<set>
<sstream>
<stack>
<stdexcept>
<streambuf>
<string>
<strstream>
<system_error>
<thread>        // missing
<tuple>
<type_traits>
<typeindex>     // missing
<unordered_map>
<unordered_set>
<utility>
<valarray>
<vector>
```

Comment: just for update AFAIK VS11 ships entire std library. Core language is another story though :)

Answer (score 21):

[cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) is a great reference for C++03.

It's getting pretty comprehensive in C++11 features these days. It doesn't have total coverage of everything, but it's getting pretty close.

Comment: I second this, the C++11 information has also increased a lot recently. I've contributed some things myself.

Answer (score 3):

I think [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx) documentation can be useful for you.

It contains documentation for libraries already implemented in VS 2010.